# A problem of compactness and connectedness

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider the subset $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by 
$A =\{(x, x\sin\frac{1}{x}) :x\in(0,1]\}$

$B = A\cup \{(0,0)\}$

I have to check for compactness and connectedness of $A$ and $B$.

Here is my attempt.

$A$ is bounded but not closed as 0 is the limit point of set $A$  but it doesn't belongs to $A$. Hence $A$ is not compact.

$B$ is compact since it is closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am not able to figure out connectedness of given sets.

Am I correct? Is there any other way to tackle this problem? I need help with this.

Thank you very much

Comment: You reasonong is correct, but you proof is of closedness of $B$ is not rigour  enough

Comment: @Norbert Could you please explain?

Comment: What about connectedness?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I have to edit sir.

Comment: Continuous image of a [connected space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) is connected, continuous image of a [compact space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space) is compact. This should help you with some parts of the exercise.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I need bit more help. I got your point. But not able to implement so for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean that $A$ is not closed because $(0,0)$ is a limit point of $A$ that is not in $A$, not $0$. That’s correct, and $B$ is closed and therefore compact, though you haven’t really justified the assertion that it’s closed.

Note that the function $$f:(0,1]\to\Bbb R^2:x\mapsto\left(x,x\sin\frac1x\right)$$ is continuous, and $(0,1]$ is connected; what does that tell you about the connectedness of $A$?

Can you show that the function $$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2:x\mapsto\begin{cases}f(x),&\text{if }x\in(0,1]\\0,&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$ is also continuous? If so, that gives you an easy way to see that $B$ is both compact and connected, because $[0,1]$ is both compact and connected.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit then rolled it back, because I was misreading.

Comment: @Brian Thank you very much. Intuitively it was clear to me but i was not able to prove it. Your answer is really helpful to me. Will try applying them for other problems too.